# how to use this class method within my Rails 3 code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am really hoping to get this resolved tonight so any help would be great.

I added this class method into my post.rb model

```
  def self.without_review
    where(review: false)
  end
```

What I am trying to do is ONLY show all posts on the site where review=false. If review=true, I want to manually approve them before they're displayed. Right now, all posts are getting displayed whether the review is true or false.

Here's my post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :load_post, only: :destroy

    def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Shared!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @post.nil?
    end

    def load_post
      @post = current_user.admin? ? Post.find(params[:id]) : current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

and here's the full post.rb model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :review
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'posts.created_at DESC'

      def self.without_review
    where(review: false)
  end


end
```

The schema of the posts table to show how "review" is set up (last row)

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.boolean  "review",          :default => false
```

The Static Pages Controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end


  def post1
    if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
    end
  end


end
```

UsersController (def show)

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@posts = @user.posts.paginate page: params[:page], :per_page => 15
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the controller/action where the actual listing of posts is generated, but I guess you have to replace `Post.all` with `Post.without_review` there.

Comment: the controller or the view? I updated the original post with the relevant portion

Comment: The controller, the view you've added is irrelevant.

Comment: You said "What I am trying to do is ONLY show all posts on the site where review=false" - show us the code that is responsible for generating this "all posts" screen.

Comment: If it's the UsersController#show view you want to change, replace `@user.posts.paginate` with `@user.posts.without_review.paginate`. Note that the name of your method is a bit misleading: without_review suggests it returns posts that were not reviewed, while in fact it does the opposite (if I understand your description correctly, that is). Consider using a flag name "reviewed" and scope named likewise.

Comment: As @MichałKwiatkowski was guessing, `@posts = @user.posts.paginate` should be replaced with `@posts = @user.posts.without_review.paginate`. Btw. this is basic Rails stuff.

Comment: I really appreciate the help Michal and iltempo. I have one last question while a lot of the information is available in this thread, how can I change the `def create` in the PostsController to make it flash "Post is being reviewed" if review=true?